# Output of certain strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

There is a code in Homepage which output strings from database:

```
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
    {
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Post" asp-route-id="@post.Id" >
            <span class="title">
                @post.Title,
                @post.Body,
                @post.Category
            </span>
        </a>
    }
```

All strings are output correctly. Each string has some variables (in table dbo.Posts and Models file Post.cs)

```
public string Title { get; set; } = "";
public string Body { get; set; } = "";
public string Category { get; set; } = "";
```

I would like that program could output on the page in table only strings consist certain value of variable "Category" and in other case string isn't output. How is it possible?

Comment: Use `table`, `tr` and `td` to render table structure... user `if(condition)` to check the value of category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter your Posts collection server-side before sending it to view. For example:

```
viewModel.Posts = GetPosts().Where(p => p.Category == "certain value");
```

Comment: I did a condition and it works correctly. However, style of code isn't good. How can I optimise?
<table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
            {
            <tr asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Post" asp-route-id="<at signpost.Id">
                <td><at sign(post.Category == "Players" ? <at sign>post.Title : "")</td>
                <td><at sign(post.Category == "Players" ? <at sign>post.Body : "")</td>
            </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
    </table>

Comment: @Antonieru why not to filter it in server-side as I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can try:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Body
            </th>
            <th>
                Category
            </th>    
        </tr> 

    <% foreach (var post in Model.Posts) { %>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>    
                <at sign>post.Id    
            </td>    
            <td>    
                <at sign>post.Title    
            </td>    
            <td>    
                <at sign>post.Body    
            </td>        
        </tr>    
    <% } %>     
    </table>
```